# iOS does not wake up application (for bluetooth events), after it is deallocated from memory

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Currently, I'm testing Bluetooth in peripheral mode on iOS. It manages to work in background, but if user uses other applications and system decides to dealloc bluetooth application, app is not relaunched when it needs to react to new bluetooth events.

Any idea how to make app respond to bluetooth events in this scenario?

Tested on iOS 11.1.1

[Prototype apps](https://github.com/Qase/BLE_Prototype_iOS) (with replication steps) to test bluetooth in peripheral modes.

Comment: Have you opted in to Bluetooth state restoration?

Comment: Such trivial mistake, thanks